Spawning a Robot in Gazebo (Fortress, ROS2 Humble, XML Launch)
I have been trying for a week to get this to work and cant figure out what the problem is.  I have can launch the URDF and display it into RVIZ properly, but cant get it to spawn in gazebo.  I had this working in ROS1 and get this working in ROS2.  Ive been all over the docs and cant figure it out. Even getting better debug info would help. What am I doing wrong ( please dont say to use python launches :D )
Code in Launch file:
 <arg name="robot_xacro" default="$(find-pkg-share aion_r1_description)/urdf/r1_base.urdf.xacro" />
  <let name="robot_urdf" value="$(command '$(find-exec xacro) $(var robot_xacro) unique_name:=$(var robot_name)')" />
  <let name="robot_urdf_topic" value="/robot_description/$(var robot_name)" />
  <!-- <let name="robot_sdf" value="$(command '$(find-exec gz) sdf -p $(var robot_urdf)')" /> -->

  <!-- Spawn in Gazebo -->
  <!-- To spawn from a topic use  -topic $(var robot_urdf_topic) -->
  <!-- To spawn from a sdf        -file  $(var robot_sdf_file) -->
  <!-- To spawn from a urdf       -param $(var robot_urdf) --> 
  <node
    pkg="ros_gz_sim"
    exec="create"
    name="$(var robot_name)_spawn_robot"
    output="screen"
    args="-world $(var world_name) -param $(var robot_urdf) -name $(var robot_name) -allow_renaming true -x $(var x) -y $(var y) -z $(var z) -R $(var roll) -P $(var pitch) -Y $(var yaw)">
  </node>

Error:
1725808642.9669485 [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/[OMITTED]/.ros/log/2024-09-08-11-17-22-966491-precision7760e-53770
1725808642.9670291 [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
1725808643.1213059 [INFO] [create-1]: process started with pid [53779]
1725808643.1214428 [INFO] [create-2]: process started with pid [53781]
1725808643.2176745 [ERROR] [create-2]: process has died [pid 53781, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/ros_gz_sim/create -world mtu_campus -param <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from [omitted for stack exchange ] | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="r1_sim">
  <!-- Importing external urdf/xacros. -->
  <material name="gray">
...
[All of the XML]
...
   </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
 -name changethisrobotname -allow_renaming true -x 10.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.1 -R 0.0 -P 0.0 -Y 0.0 -v 4 --ros-args -r __node:=changethisrobotname_spawn_robot'].
1725808643.2297444 [ERROR] [create-1]: process has died [pid 53779, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/ros_gz_sim/create -world mtu_campus -param <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
...
[All of the XML]
...
   </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
 -name changethisrobotname -allow_renaming true -x 10.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.1 -R 0.0 -P 0.0 -Y 0.0 --ros-args -r __node:=changethisrobotname_spawn_robot'].

